# Building a GUI application cannot find #include_next "<....h>"

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I am trying to use `Qt` to design my application (which will utilize my library), but I am getting an error from `Qt`. I first installed `Qt` through `msys2` like this:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-qt6
```

I then created a `CMakeLists.txt` that looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(test VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY bin)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\include")
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\lib")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
qt_standard_project_setup()

qt_add_executable(
  app
    app/main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(
  app
  PRIVATE
    Qt6::Widgets
)

set_target_properties(app PROPERTIES
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE ON
)
```

Then Created the `app/main.cpp` file:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  return app.exec();
}
```

But, when I build the code, I get the following error:

```
[build] In file included from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/qt6/QtCore/qnumeric.h:15,
[build]                  from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/qt6/QtCore/qglobal.h:62,
[build]                  from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/qt6/QtGui/qtguiglobal.h:7,
[build]                  from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/qt6/QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h:7,
[build]                  from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/qt6/QtWidgets/qapplication.h:7,
[build]                  from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/qt6/QtWidgets/QApplication:1,
[build]                  from C:\Users\untun\Documents\vscode\draw\draw\app\main.cpp:1:
[build] C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/cmath:47:15: fatal error: math.h: No such file or directory
[build]    47 | #include_next <math.h>
[build]       |               ^~~~~~~~
```

Any ideas as to why I am getting this error? Did I not install everything or something?

### Edit

I have now also tried with GTK and git the same error but with a different include:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gtk4
```

With this cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(draw VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY bin)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK4 REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET gtk4)

add_executable(app main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
  app
  PRIVATE
    PkgConfig::GTK4
)
```

And this cpp file:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

using namespace std;

static void activate(GtkApplication *app) {
  GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new("com.example.GtkApplication",
                                            G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  return g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
}
```

Resulting in this error:

```
[build] In file included from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:43,
[build]                  from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:4097,
[build]                  from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/string:54,
[build]                  from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
[build]                  from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
[build]                  from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/ios:44,
[build]                  from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/ostream:40,
[build]                  from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/iostream:41,
[build]                  from C:\Users\untun\Documents\vscode\draw\draw\src\app\main.cpp:3:
[build] C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/cstdlib:79:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
[build]    79 | #include_next <stdlib.h>
[build]       |               ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: What happens if you don't override `CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH` etc? This is wrong anyway.

Comment: @Osyotr same error message.

Comment: Can you compile simple programs with this toolchain? Did you also clean cmake cache?

Comment: I am able to compile other applications

Comment: I just remembered that I did run `pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-qt6-base` before the one above, but I assume the one I ran above just overwrote it. Not sure if this makes a difference. I have also cleaned the cache and still nothing.

Comment: Since posting this question, I tried to setup GTK instead, and I again get the same error message but for a different include `#include_next <stdlib.h>`

Comment: Might be a gcc bug: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/10761

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by adding the following to my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
include_directories(
  BEFORE
  SYSTEM
    "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\include\\c++\\13.2.0"
)
```