# The compiler can't find "math.h" header

Tags: c++, qt, g++

I am trying to compile a Qt Project. I run this command:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-12 --sysroot=/home/mustafa/Desktop
/Programming/QtProjects -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -I 
/usr/include/c++/12 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/home/mustafa
/Desktop/Programming/QtProjects/build-pcm2-Desktop-Debug/pcm2_autogen
/include -isystem /home/mustafa/Qt/6.6.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore -isystem 
/home/mustafa/Qt/6.6.1/gcc_64/include -isystem /home/mustafa/Qt/6.6.1
/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -isystem /home/mustafa/Qt/6.6.1/gcc_64
/include/QtWidgets -isystem /home/mustafa/Qt/6.6.1/gcc_64/include/QtGui 
-isystem /usr/include -DQT_QML_DEBUG -g -std=gnu++17 -fdiagnostics-
color=always -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/pcm2.dir/mainwindow.cpp.o -MF 
CMakeFiles/pcm2.dir/mainwindow.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/pcm2.dir
/mainwindow.cpp.o -c /home/mustafa/Desktop/Programming/QtProjects
/pcm2/mainwindow.cpp
```

It has the flag `-isystem /usr/include`, which (I think) means that the compiler should look at this directory to find a header. This directory has the header `math.h`. However, it gives the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/12/cmath:45:15: fatal error: math.h: No such file or directory
   45 | #include_next <math.h>
      |               ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I also tried adding `-I /usr/include/c++/12` to the command, since the directory `/usr/include/c++/12` also has the header *math.h*, but it didn't make a difference. I still got the same error.

Is it because it is `#include_next` instead of `#include`? Or is it something else?

Adding the below did not help:

```
include_directories(BEFORE SYSTEM
/usr/include
/usr/include/c++/12
)
```

After Clifford said that I maybe overcomplicated things, I realized that `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` wasn't included before, I included it myself. Now I deleted that line, so that cmake file is exactly the way it was when I first installed Qt. Now it looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(pcm2 VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(pcm2
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET pcm2 APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(pcm2 SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(pcm2
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(pcm2 PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)

# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
if(${QT_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 6.1.0)
  set(BUNDLE_ID_OPTION MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.pcm2)
endif()
set_target_properties(pcm2 PROPERTIES
    ${BUNDLE_ID_OPTION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS pcm2
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(pcm2)
endif()
```

but now I still get the same error.
and now the build process looks like this

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-12 --sysroot=/home/mustafa/Desktop
/Programming/QtProjects -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB 
-I/home/mustafa/Desktop/Programming/QtProjects/build-pcm3-Desktop-
Debug/pcm3_autogen/include -isystem /home/mustafa/Qt/6.6.1/gcc_64
/include/QtCore -isystem /home/mustafa/Qt/6.6.1/gcc_64/include -isystem 
/home/mustafa/Qt/6.6.1/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -isystem /home/mustafa
/Qt/6.6.1/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -isystem /home/mustafa/Qt/6.6.1
/gcc_64/include/QtGui -isystem /usr/include -DQT_QML_DEBUG -g 
-std=gnu++17 -fdiagnostics-color=always -fPIC -MD -MT 
CMakeFiles/pcm3.dir/pcm3_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o -MF 
CMakeFiles/pcm3.dir/pcm3_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o.d -o 
CMakeFiles/pcm3.dir/pcm3_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o -c 
/home/mustafa/Desktop/Programming/QtProjects/build-pcm3-Desktop-
Debug/pcm3_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp
```

It now doesn't have `-I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu`, but still the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Building a GUI application cannot find #include_next <....h>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77789097/building-a-gui-application-cannot-find-include-next-h).

Comment: `#include_next` means include the file but only search in `-I` and `-isystem` paths listed after the current path.  So `/usr/include/c++/12` where you say `math.h` exists will not be searched it will continue searching from `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu`.  Normally standard headers are found using `-isystem` or environment default paths.  You seem to be over-specifying your build.  Perhaps by trying to control it so closely you are forcing the compiler to do things incorrectly that it would have otherwise got right by default.